# laravel-doctrine lazy loading set up in mapping not taking effect

Tags: php, laravel, doctrine-orm, doctrine, lazy-loading

I've checked other questions on here and can't find anything definite.

I am trying ot build an api endpoint using an existing database. The tables are massive, and the tables that they join to are equally massive.

I want to find an animal in the animal table with ID `111`.

I have the mapping set up and a controller that calls it like this:

```
public function get($id)
{
    $animal = EntityManager::getRepository(Animal::class)->find(111);
    var_dump($animal);
    die();
}
```

For now I'm just `var_dump`'ing to confirm that the data I'm retrieving is accurate. My problem is that even though I've set up all the relationships to other tables to lazy load, it is still loading everything.

Example of lazy loading set up in the mapping:

```
/**
 * @var \Contact
 *
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Contact", fetch="LAZY")
 * @ORM\JoinColumns({
 *   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="animaldata_billingcontact", referencedColumnName="contact_id")
 * })
 */
```

I want to just load the contact id, not the entire contact object, because this is slowing down my call significantly.

Comment: I think lazy is the default? Are you looking for `fetch="EXTRA_LAZY"`?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, unfortunately that didn't do the trick - I think I'm going to stop var_dumping the whole thing and start looking for a different way to do it.

Comment: Changing the outcome by looking at it? Meow :) Laravel/Doctrine world offer any SQL profiling tools? Wanna say Doctrine 2.0 > has `setSQLLogger` function.

Comment: Apologies but I don't understand your previous comment

Comment: I think what is being suggested is that you look at the actual sql queries that are being executed.  var_dump is probably causing the loading to occur.  Symfony has this sort of logger builtin.  I'm sure Laravel has something similar.

Comment: I'll check it out, thanks!